# Creating expandable HTML5 banner for DoubleClick studio in Flash CC HTML Canvas

Tags: html, flash, html5-canvas, double-click-advertising

Has anyone done this?

Would end up being two flash files published to HTML5 then the DCS (double-click studio code) added and consolidated into one HTML file so it can be uploaded?

Answer (score 1):

Doubleclick Studio has awesome HTML5 Rich Media templates. Start there. Going from DC's AS3 templates whhich use components, and using Flash CC to convert won't work. THE AS3 API won't translate and the components won;t work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it, it'll give you many headaches if you are in fact able to do it. Google DoubleClick want you to use Google Web Designer and they're notorious for not approving rich media banner units to get you 'into their GWD funnel' as it were.